# How to bless boot partition for Ubuntu 22.04 on 2009 MacBook Pro

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi, macbook-pro

I have performed a full-disk install of Ubuntu 22.04 on an old MacBook Pro (MacBookPro5,2 from 2009, Core 2 Duo) machine completely wiping OS X in the process.

I'm now facing the known issue of the 30-second white screen delay on boot. I already figured out I have to use the OS X `bless` command to set Ubuntu as the boot partition. My question is what command-line arguments do I have to pass exactly? All examples on the internet make use of the `--legacy` option and talk about BIOS mode, but from what I could figure out my Ubuntu installation is using EFI ([the `/sys/firmware/efi` directory exists](https://askubuntu.com/a/162896/1484565)).

Am I right in assuming then that I shouldn't use the `--legacy` option when blessing the partition? Also which partition do I have to bless? The `/dev/sda1` one?

Here's the output of `df -h` when run in Ubuntu:

```
t30@macbook:~$ df -h
tmpfs           770M    1,7M  768M    1% /run
/dev/sda2       457G     12G  423G    3% /
tmpfs           3,8G       0  3,8G    0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M    4,0K  5,0M    1% /run/lock
/dev/sda1       511M    6,1M  505M    2% /boot/efi
tmpfs           770M     52K  770M    1% /run/user/1000
```

So would I just invoke `bless` like this (replacing `/dev/sda1` with whatever it's mounted as under `bless`)?

```
bless --device /dev/sda1 --setBoot
```

---

So after trying out different variations, here are the results:

`bless --device /dev/disk0s1 --setBoot`
doesn't appear to do anything. Still long timeout on white screen. System still booting afterwards.

`bless --device /dev/disk0s2 --setBoot` same as above.

`bless --device /dev/disk0s1 --setBoot --legacy` still long timeout on white screen. After that system goes to black screen and won't boot into Ubuntu.

There are only `/dev/disk0s1` and `/dev/disk0s2` listed in fdisk for `/dev/disk0`. I'm assuming `/dev/disk0s1` is `/boot/efi`, but I have no idea.

Comment: Bless must have something to do with Mac? If so it is a Mac question and not for this site.

Comment: The apple people point me here though saying it's a linux problem, so it's an unaskable question?

Comment: You tried the Mac site of Stack Exchange?

Comment: I rule this question as on topic.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr:** One possible command would be `bless --folder /Volumes/EFI --file /Volumes/EFI/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi --setBoot`.

Since the question also involves boot times, I have included the boot times and specs on my Mac. I would expect the OP's Mac to be slower than my Mac.

My Mac has the following specs:

- iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2011)
- 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5
- 16 GB 1333 MHz DDR3
- 1 TB SATA II (3 Gb/s) internal HDD

The table below shows the operating systems currently installed on my Mac.

| Operating System | Version | Architecture | Boot Method | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Windows 11 Pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/449530/upgrading-from-windows-10-to-windows-11-for-free) | 22H2 | AMD64 | BIOS | Internal HDD |
| macOS High Sierra | 10.13.6 | AMD64 | EFI | Internal HDD |
| Ubuntu | 22.04.1 LTS | AMD64 | EFI | Internal HDD |

I took the following steps to test using the `bless` command to set Ubuntu as the default operating system to boot.

1. Started the Mac and held down the <kbd>option</kbd> key until the Mac Startup Manager icons appeared.
2. Choose to boot from the macOS High Sierra Recovery volume on the internal drive.
3. Mounted the only EFI volume (`/dev/disk0s1`) on `/Volumes/EFI`.
4. Entered the following command in a Terminal window.<sup>†</sup>

   ```
   bless --folder /Volumes/EFI --file /Volumes/EFI/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi --setBoot
   ```
5. Restarted the Mac, which booted GRUB, then Ubuntu.

<sup>†This is the command the OP posted in a [comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/668998).</sup>

Table of Boot Timing is shown below. Here, GRUB is configured to wait 10 seconds and Ubuntu has automatic login turned on.

| Event | Duration | Total Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Between power on and start of white screen | 6.75 | 6.75 |
| White screen is visible | 8.74 | 15.50 |
| Between end of white screen and Desktop appearing | 1:35.65 | 1:51.16 |

Below is the contents of the current `/etc/default/grub` file on my Mac.

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
```

Comment: Can you add a tl;dr? Are you saying there is actually not a problem?

Comment: @OrganicMarble: I added a tl;dr. I assume the OP's problem is real. However, previous posts here at [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284399/how-can-i-stop-ubuntu-taking-over-as-default-os-on-mac-or-at-least-reset-macos) and over at [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/394643/wierd-problem-after-doing-a-triple-boot-os-x-ubuntu-20-04-kali-linux) involve trying to get Mac to do the opposite of what the OP is asking for.